# bash + arithmetic calculation with bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, awk, bc

I need to do the follwing with bash 
what is the elegant way ? to get the final $sum value

```
worker_machine=32
executors_per_node=3

executer=$worker_machine/$executors_per_node-1
spare=$executer X 0.07 
sum=$executer-$spare ( with round the number to down ) 

example:

32/3 = 10 - 1 = 9
9 X 0.7 = 0.6
9 – 0.6 = 8 ( with round the number to down )
```

Comment: The shell will not do floating point arithmetics for you, so that rules out e.g. `$(( ... ))`. The best option would be to use `awk` IMHO.

Comment: can you so me the complete answer please

Comment: Patience is a virtue ;-)

Comment: Is the first example (32/3)-1 = 10 - 1 = 9? This is, what $((32/3-1)) will perform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `awk`, taking values from shell variables:

```
awk -v n="$worker_machine" -v m="$executors_per_node" \
    'BEGIN { printf("%d\n", 0.93 * (n / m - 1)) }' /dev/null
```

The `awk` script doesn't get any input as usual, so we use `/dev/null` as input file and do our calculation and output in a `BEGIN` block.

Using `bc`:

```
sum=$( printf '0.93 * (%d / %d - 1)\n' "$worker_machine" "$executors_per_node" | bc )
printf '%.0f\n' "$sum"
```

Using `dc`:

```
sum=$( printf '%d\n%d\n/\n1\n-\n0.93\n*\np\n' "$worker_machine" "$executors_per_node" | dc )
printf '%.0f\n' "$sum"
```

Comment: @Inian But when it's done with the `BEGIN` block, it would wait for input from the terminal if not provided a file.

Comment: @Inian Hrm... no it doesn't. My bad. But I'll leave it in there because it serves to document the fact that we're not reading from anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

The shell is able to to the math (as integers, which round down):

```
$ sum=$(( ( worker_machine/executors_per_node-1 ) * 93 / 100 ))
$ echo "$sum"
8
```

The default scale for bc is 0, so the results of division would be integers:

```
$ sum=$(bc <<<"($worker_machine / $executors_per_node - 1)*93/100")
$ echo "$sum"
8
```

As we want an integer, we may ask awk for one

```
$ sum=$(awk -v m="$worker_machine" -v n="$executors_per_node" 'BEGIN{ print( int((m/n-1)*93/100) )}' /dev/null)
$ echo "$sum"
8
```